# How can I use getElementsByClassName(<classname>).outerHTML="" to hide a <div> when there are multiple names for the div's class?

Tags: html, hide

I am trying to learn how to hide `<div>` sections on a webpage, using javascript `getElementsByClassName("<classname>").outerHTML=""`.

It all works great if the element I am hiding e.g. `<div class="someclassname">Some content I want to hide</div>`. Or, I have success if using `getElementByID("<divId>")` if working with e.g. `<div id="somedivID">`.

The problem is, when wanting to hide a `<div>` that has no `id` and when there are multiple names listed for the div's class such as below:

```
<div class="cake forest carousel">Some content I want to hide.</div>
```

How can I hide such a div that has not id and no single class name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For classes, you can use `document.querySelectorAll()` along with css selectors, like this:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.cake')[0].style.display = 'none';
});
```

```html
<div class="cake forest carousel">Some content I want to hide.</div>
<button>Hide content</button>
```

With classNames, remember that you can specify ALL the classNames (sometimes that is useful to pinpoint one element if there are other elements that contain part of the classList:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.cake.forest.carousel')[0] . . .
```

Also note that `document.querySelectorAll()` returns a *collection*, not a string - which is why it is necessary to use the `[0]` notation to choose the first element returned in the collection.

Using `getElementsByClassName()` is much the same idea - again, it returns a collection and one must either use the `[0]` notation to get the first element (usually if only one is returned), or a `forEach()` loop to choose the desired element based on other criteria.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementsByClassName('cake forest')[0].style.display = 'none';
});
```

```html
<div class="cake forest carousel">This div has classes cake, forest and carousel</div>
<div class="cake">This div only has class cake</div>
<button>Hide divs with classes cake AND forest</button>
```

Comment: Awesome, it worked! Thank you thank you! I owe you a beer!